# Express Variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm pretty new to use R and tried to use an for loop.

I have recurring data with different number of columns (normally between 3 and 5), the first one is a timestamp, the second a temperature.

Similar like this:

```
test=data.frame(
  date=c("10:10","10:20","10:30","10:40","10:50"),
  temp=c(23.5,23.6,23.4,22.7,23.5),
  v1=rnorm(5),
  v2=rnorm(5),
  v3=rnorm(5)
```

In the script I need to convert v1-v3, till now I adapted the R script every run to the number of columns and did it this way (working with tibbles:

```
test=as.tibble(test)
test <- test %>% 
  mutate(con_v1 =v1*temp,
         con_v2 =v2*temp,
         con_v3 =v3*temp)
```

Now I want to create a script which adapts automatically to the number of columns.
My approach is a for loop:

```
test=as.tibble(test)
var_col=ncol(test)-2

for (i in 1:var_col) {
  test %>% 
       mutate(paste('con_v',i,sep="")=temp*get(paste('v',i,sep="")))
}
```

I know the part of the function which won't work is:

```
paste('con_v',i,sep="")
```

I searched now for hours and didn`t find a solution or a workaround. 
Is there a possibility to express this part to use it as name?

Greetings 
Olo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses base R:

```
transform(test, con = test[-(1:2)] * temp)
```

giving:

```
   date temp         v1         v2         v3     con.v1     con.v2    con.v3
1 10:10 23.5 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812 -14.721665 -19.281007  35.52686
2 10:20 23.6  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432   4.333982  11.503326   9.20030
3 10:30 23.4 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406 -19.553710  17.276798 -14.53703
4 10:40 22.7  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999  36.212874  13.070237 -50.27369
5 10:50 23.5  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309   7.743433  -7.176627  26.43588
```

### Note 1

If the underscores in the names are important then if `DF` is the output data frame above this will change the dots in the names to undersore:

```
names(DF) <- chartr(".", "_", names(DF))
```

### Note 2

One problem is if `test` has only one column after the first 2, i.e. 3 columns in total.  If that can never happen you can disregard this Note and just use the simpler solution above but if it can happen then observe that in that case the naming comes out  differently.

```
transform(test, con = test[3] * temp)
```

giving:

```
   date temp          v1         v2         v3       v1.1
1 10:10 23.5 -0.80204498 -0.8949888 -0.4866425 -18.848057
2 10:20 23.6 -0.36470704 -0.7613484 -0.3088144  -8.607086
3 10:30 23.4  0.11636106 -0.1432790 -1.3531962   2.722849
4 10:40 22.7 -0.04725339  0.4934565 -0.9005468  -1.072652
5 10:50 23.5 -0.31788301 -0.3664272  0.5048562  -7.470251
```

Emil Bode pointed out that this works consistently for one or more columns:

```
do.call("transform", c(list(test), con = test[3] * test$temp))
```

giving:

```
   date temp          v1         v2         v3     con.v1
1 10:10 23.5 -0.80204498 -0.8949888 -0.4866425 -18.848057
2 10:20 23.6 -0.36470704 -0.7613484 -0.3088144  -8.607086
3 10:30 23.4  0.11636106 -0.1432790 -1.3531962   2.722849
4 10:40 22.7 -0.04725339  0.4934565 -0.9005468  -1.072652
5 10:50 23.5 -0.31788301 -0.3664272  0.5048562  -7.470251
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works fine. Means this that there is no possibility to change this "paste('con_v',i,sep="")" in a usabele variable name?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with tidyverse scoped functions :

```
test <- test %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("v\\d+")),funs(.*temp)) %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("v\\d+")),funs(paste0("con_",.))) %>%
  select(-c(1,2)) %>%
  bind_cols(test,.)
```

With data :

```
set.seed(42)
test=data.frame(
  date=c("10:10","10:20","10:30","10:40","10:50"),
  temp=c(23.5,23.6,23.4,22.7,23.5),
  v1=rnorm(5),
  v2=rnorm(5),
  v3=rnorm(5))
test=as.tibble(test)

## A tibble: 5 x 8
#  date   temp     v1      v2     v3 con_v1 con_v2 con_v3
#  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 10:10  23.5  1.37  -0.106   1.30   32.2   -2.49  30.7 
#2 10:20  23.6 -0.565  1.51    2.29  -13.3   35.7   54.0 
#3 10:30  23.4  0.363 -0.0947 -1.39    8.50  -2.22 -32.5 
#4 10:40  22.7  0.633  2.02   -0.279  14.4   45.8   -6.33
#5 10:50  23.5  0.404 -0.0627 -0.133   9.50  -1.47  -3.13
```